# Redox titrations : Oxidation of metallic Iron by Potassium Dichromate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, redox

> $\pu{0.31 g}$ of an alloy of $\ce{Fe + Cu}$ was dissolved in excess of diluted $\ce{H2SO4}$, and the solution was made up to $\pu{100 ml}$. $\pu{20 ml}$ of this solution required $\pu{3 ml}$ of $\frac{N}{10} \ce{K2Cr2O7}$ solution for the oxidation. The percentage purity (in closest value) of $\ce{Fe}$ in wire is ____.

I am approaching the problem with the following method. Let us assume the weight of $\ce{Fe}$ in the alloy to be $x$ grams. By the law of chemical equivalence, we know that the number of equivalents of $\ce{Fe}$ is equal to the number of equivalents of $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$.

To find the number of equivalents of $\ce{Fe}$ we need the corresponding chemical equation which I tried to find in vain on Google. I just want to know the oxidation state $\ce{Fe}$ would acquire. Then, I can easily answer this problem by substituting $n$ (number of electrons lost by $\ce{Fe}$) in the equivalence equation for this particular problem:
$1000n / 280 = 1/10$. From here I can easily calculate the percentage purity of $\ce{Fe}$.

Comment: Google cannot find these calculations, because such calculations are no longer taught so probably no one has webpages on this topic. They are obsolete (although some chemical industries still use it). Search normality calculations or see solved examples in your textbook which is still using normality.

Comment: You should be able to formulate the chemical equation of the reaction on your own, knowing the basics of chemistry of iron and chromium.

Comment: There is no problem in doing the mathematics. I just can't find the Reaction involved here. I will once again try to find it in my textbook. Thank you guys.

Comment: That was my point. You should not need to search for it. Hint: Cr:  +VI->+III    Fe:  0->+III

Comment: The beauty of normality calculations is that you do not need a chemical equation for this problem. Plug and chug in C1V1=C2V2. C1 is Fe conc. in normality, V1 is volume of iron sample, C2 is concentration of K2Cr2O7 in normality and V2 is the burette volume.

Comment: The last hint is that you should know how to calculate the equivalent weight of Fe2+. Search these terms in your textbook.

Comment: I have doubts about iron and copper miscibility.

Comment: Yeah I was also thinking about the oxidation of copper by iron. But in a similar problem like this where some other metals purity was to be found, they neglected the reaction. I dont know why.

Comment: Oops sorry, I have forgotten the dissolution step. Then obviously Fe: +2 -> +3.  As Cu is filtered out, Fe^3+ will not oxidize it. My miscible point was about eventual impossibility to make Fe/Cu alloy. The task may be made up. It also does mention necessary filtering undissolved Cu.

Answer (score 0):

Let's reason with molar units.
Expressed in molar units, $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$ N/$10$ is $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$ M/$60$.

$3$ mL $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$ N/$10$ contains $0.003/10$ equivalent.

In molar units $0.003/10$ equivalent is $0.003/60$ mol $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$ = $0.05$ mmol $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$.

The equation of the titration becomes : $$\ce{Cr2O7^{2-} + 6 Fe^{2+} + 14 H+ -> 2 Cr^{3+} + 6 Fe^{3+} + 7 H2O}$$ Because of the coefficient $6$ in front of $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ in the equation, $0.05$ mmol $\ce{Cr2O7^{2-}}$ has reacted with $6$ times more $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ = $0.3$ mmol $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$. This amount of $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ comes from the same amount of metallic Iron, i.e. $\ce{0.3}$ mmole $\ce{Fe}$, because the reaction of iron with a diluted acid is  $$\ce{Fe + 2 H+ -> Fe^{2+} + H2}$$ But the initial solution of $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ had a volume of $100$ mL, and only $20$ mL was used for titration. It means that the initial metallic sample contained $5$ times more iron than $0.3$ mmol, which is $1.5$ mmol $\ce{Fe}$.
As $1.5$ mmol $\ce{Fe}$ weighs $1.5·56$ mg = $84$ mg, it means that the proportion of iron in the initial sample is $\frac{0.084}{0.31} = 27.1$%